# After duplicating a sheet, remove formulas and retain values/formats

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet "SourceData" that has a lot of formulas to develop a proposal price based on variables entered on the sheet "Inputs". I need script to generateNewScope, where the "SourceData" sheet is duplicated, formulas removed from the duplicate, and it's renamed from "Copy of SourceData" to 1, then 2, then 3, etc.

I'm close! I can duplicate and rename, and I've gotten a different script to the point where it removes the formulas, but that one removed formulas from both "SourceData" AND "1". I just need to add additional actions here that essentially copy/paste values only directly in the same spot, or just a remove formulas action.

```
function generateNewScope() {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("SourceData"));
    var ns = ss.duplicateActiveSheet(),
    allSheets = ss.getSheets();
    ns.setName(allSheets.length - 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy a sheet in a Spreadsheet.
- You want to copy only values without the formulas.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, your script is modified.
- Only values are copied using `copyTo()` after the sheet was copied.

#### Modified script:

```
function generateNewScope() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("SourceData"));
  var ns = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();

  var range = ns.getDataRange(); // Added
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true}); // Added

  allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  ns.setName(allSheets.length - 4);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is perfect, @tanaike! Thank you. I couldn't figure out the Range variable. I'll have to read into that one more.

Comment: @Kelly Danner Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.